# Customize Magento checkout process

Tags: magento

I have products with individual landing pages.  I want the landing pages to contain everything needed to checkout with that product. This includes a dropdown to select the quantity of the product desired, shipping information and billing information.  Is this possible?   In default Magento, you can't get to the checkout process without first having an item in the cart.

Comment: Not without customization.

Answer (score 2):

Default Magento allows you to choose where to redirect after a product is added to cart: to the cart overview or back to the page where the "Add to Cart" button was clicked. Using a similar approach you can create an extension that overrides the 'addAction' method of the cart controller to redirect to the checkout page immediately after a product is added to cart.

You can't go to checkout with an empty shopping cart, but redirecting after the add to cart action allows customers to skip the cart page, if that is what you intend to achieve.

It is also possible to use the billing and shipping information the customer submits in the landing page for the checkout - your extension will have to validate it and save into the quote object as if it was submitted in the respective checkout steps.

Developing such an extension would not be a simple task - checkout is a very sensitive matter.